# Using Stream Analytics to insert data into CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have problems that my CosmosDB is busy and therefore i am losing data since the Stream Analyzer isn't buffering data.

My current Azure setup is as follows:

WebAPI -> EventHub -> Stream Analytics job -> CosmosDB

My issue is that if i start my stream back in time and it then has alot of records, the CosmosDB is busy and returns HTTP 429 (Exceeded limit), this will then cause me to have dataloss.

Is there a way to throttle the Stream Analytics job or should i make a completely different design to avoid having dataloss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following MSDN ASA does in fact retry on 429, i just expected another behavior.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/04/18/troubleshooting-azure-stream-analytics-jobs-on-new-portal-2/

Comment: Your link is broken.  It is generally better if you provide the link alongside the relevant part of the linked page to guard against dead links.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to change the design to avoid having dataloss, since the we couldn't throttle the Stream Analytics job.

I suggest you could try to use [Stream Analytics Window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions)'s [Tumbling Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn835055.aspx).

> Tumbling window functions are used to segment a data stream into distinct time segments and perform a function against them

I suggest you could use this function to get the data from a period of time. Then you could combine these data into one document and store into the DB.

For example, you could set the windows to 1 seconds. It means you insert 60 records to the db in one minutes.

Comment: My current implementation requires every Event in the EventHub to be a document in CosmosDB :( So currently my Stream analytics job does something like "Select * FROM x into y". So im afraid i cant really use windows here (Though its a cool function i didnt know about)

Comment: In my opinion, in one document you could store multiple event as its property. You just need change the querying. If you don't want to use this, I suggest you could consider scaling your RU.

Answer (score 0):

How many RU have you provisioned for your collection? Have you tried simply scaling your collection to meet the demand? CosmosDB also recently introduced the concept of RU/minute which can help in backpressure scenarios as it provides additional throughput once you've exceeded your provisioned throughput per second.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units-per-minute) provides a good introduction to using RU/minute.

[The Azure Dev blog talks about this more in detail](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-case-study-around-ru-min-with-the-universal-store-team/). Relevant quote from the article (the bolding is mine for emphasis)

To test RU/m, we designed the catchup or failure recovery test in our dev environment. Previously we allocated 300K RU/s for the collection. We enabled RU/m and reduced compute capacity from 300K RU/second to 100K RU/second. This gave us extra 1M RU/m. To push our writes to the limit and test our catchup scenario we simulated an upstream failure. **We stopped streaming for about 20 hours. We then started streaming backlog data and observed if the application could catchup with the lower RU/s plus additional RU/m.** The dev environment also had the same load as we see in production.

Comment: I have scaled it alot, but that does not change the fact that when my CosmosDB is under load (Heavy query or what not) i will lose data with my current setup. My setup is around 100GB running through in 24hours, so scaling any further is not really the solution here :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many RU/second are you currently using? 100 GB every 24 hours really isn't that much to ingest

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-case-study-around-ru-min-with-the-universal-store-team/ You might be interested in this case study on how RU/minute can be used. They are ingesting 2 TB per day

Comment: Its very much in spikes (Spikes longer than 1 minute), so currently to have a stable load without dataloss i run around 50k RU

Comment: Did you read either of the articles I've linked regarding RU/m? I think you're misunderstanding how it works. It can support backpressure for periods much longer than a single minute. I've updated my answer with more information

Comment: Yes i have read both articles before i made my question in here. But if you have a look at how RU/m is provisioned it is done per 60s (see first picture in your first link). meaning 5k RU/s gives 50k RU/Minute which averages to an extra 833 RU/s. But having a longer period, 5minutes, of a load of 15k RU/s would require a higher Request units for this "spike". I think the issue here is that my definition of spike is quite much longer than what Microsoft visions. So im back to the original question, can this be done in another way so i dont have to overscale my DB.

Comment: Just asking, what is your definition of a spike? 1h? Longer? Just asking. Would a queue/blob combination allow you to stretch things a bit?

Comment: Currently the "spike" is some initial load up of alot of data, so potentionally 2days.. currently im running my CosmosDB on max RU/s (100k) and still getting some 429 responses, so this setup is absolutely not correct..